# SQL error using FR3DLdapBundle and FOSUserBundle with Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fr3dldapbundle

When I log out and try to log back in again, it gives me the same error:

> (An exception occurred while executing ‘INSERT INTO fos_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, dn, code_utilisateur) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)’ with params [“riemann”, “riemann”, “riemann@ldap.forumsys.com”, “riemann@ldap.forumsys.com”, 1, null, “”, “2018-05-23 21:26:15”, null, null, “a:1:{i:0;s:9:\”ROLE_USER\”;}”, “uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com”, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ ‘riemann@ldap.forumsys.com’ pour la clef ‘UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF’)

As if it is trying to insert at the places to update the user.

Comment: i think your form action is register, but should be login

Comment: show us your template of login page

Comment: Hi there Jalal. Did you chain your providers exactly as per my [Symfony AD Integration article](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/) and @Maks3w 's answer? He does the support for the bundle, so this is probably the correct answer. I based my tutorial on his support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of the chain providers.

`providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]`